# Using a string as variable in R

Tags: r

I have large number of dataframes. These dataframes are named generally as `testing_someName_coo` , `testing_someName_csr`, and `testing_someName_hyb`. Here someName represents just different names. There are approximately 50 names.

The contents of these files are as follows

```
V1     V2
Alice  some value  
Bob    some value
 .
 .
Ross   some value
```

the second and third data frames also consists of records in the same format. The first column `V1` is the same in all the three dataframes. I initially wanted to rename the columns in all the three dataframes and combine them on the basis of first column. Hence I wrote the following code:

```
colnames(testing_someName_coo) <- c("name", "coo")
colnames(testing_someName_csr) <- c("name", "csr")
colnames(testing_someName_dia) <- c("name", "dia")
temp1 <- merge(testing_someName_coo,testing_someName_csr,by= "name")
temp1 <- merge(temp1,testing_someName_hyb,by= "name")
```

This works fine, But since I have large number of dataset I thought I will write a function to which will pass `someName` as a parameter and perform the above functionality. So I wrote the following code:

```
mergetiming <- function(name){
colnames(as.name(paste("testing",name,"coo",sep= "_"))) <- c("name", "coo")
colnames(as.name(paste("testing",name,"csr",sep= "_"))) <- c("name", "csr")
colnames(as.name(paste("testing",name,"dia",sep= "_")) <- c("name",   "dia")
//merge commannd here as before but using as.name(paste("testing",name,"dia",sep= "_")
}
```

But then I receive an error

```
Error in colnames(as.name(paste("testing", name, "coo", sep = "_"))) <- c("name",  : 
 target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

What would be the best way of doing this without doing this manually.

Comment: Use a [list of data frames](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061).

Comment: Others have answered questions on this topic. Have you done a search for "merge multiple data frames"? It involves something like `Reduce("merge", mydatalist)`